# Swapping out images repeatedly at a high frame rate on iOS + Javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html

Hey all what I am trying to implement is somethting where a user can slide a slider and update an image as the slider moves around. Sometimes the framerate will be ~30 fps.

What I have tried:

- Use an img tag and set the src directly to the respective image.
- Use a single div and set the background-image property to the respective image.
- Use one div for each image and adjust their z-indices.
- Use one div for each image and adjust their opacity.
- Use one div for each image and adjust their opacity via CSS3 animation.
- Keep a buffer of images both adjusting opacity or z-index and loading the correct image.

Any thoughts? Or is what I'm trying to do impossible? I have also tried using a video for the same purpose but the seek time is too long.

```
const FPS = 60;
var self = this;
setInterval(
        function() {
                self.setCurrentImageByIndex((self._currentImageIndex + 1) % 169);
        },
        1000 / FPS
);
```

Comment: I don't know the state of iPhone's stock browser, but AFAIK all modern browsers has hardware acceleration for images and, in case of Firefox, DOM layout as well. Canvas is older then CSS3 animations, and both are accelerated.  If everything you tried tops at ~30 fps, then the cause may be in other part of the code. For example are you using requestAnimationFrame or have a fixed duration for setTimeout?  Does it cap on your lovely Mac?

Comment: On the desktop it works wonderfully.

Comment: Digged around a little bit. It seems that iPhone, esp. iPhone 4 which has to draw four times the pixel because of retina display, does not have great HTML5 graphic performance. There can be many reasons, but have you tried to fix the display scale? http://impactjs.com/documentation/impact-on-mobile-platforms

Answer (score 0):

The techniques you listed are old fashioned,since you are developing application on iOS platform. You can use modern technique like `canvas` to draw the image, it's verfy fast on iOS.

And as far as i know canvas on iOS is hardware accelerated.

Here is an example code to draw an image using canvas:

```
  function draw() {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function(){
      ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(30,96);
      ctx.lineTo(70,66);
      ctx.lineTo(103,76);
      ctx.lineTo(170,15);
      ctx.stroke();
    };
    img.src = 'images/backdrop.png';
  }
```

There is a [tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images) on MDN